# Editing tpl files in prestashop doesn't seem to do anything

Tags: html, templates, smarty, prestashop

I have "Advanced Homepage Product List" Module installed in prestashop.
In the configuration, I am using "Your Template Style", I tried to edit
/var/www/html/modules/prodcat/views/templates/hook/prodcat.tpl

it seems to be the one being used because it has

```
<div class="block products_block clearfix">
```

and

```
 <h4 class="title_block" style="margin-bottom:0px; ">
```

which appear when i use inspect element on the website.
Haven't seen any other files that are similar to this.

I tried to edit it. Like remove the `<h4>` element but it doesn't seem to do anything.
Am I edting the wrong file? or do i have to do something inorder for my changes to take effect?

Comment: are you tried to clear cache? Also, I do not have this module, but check `prodcat.php` file method `hookDisplayHome` I think, what tpl file there is assigned - `prodcat.tpl`? If yes, then you edit right file.

Comment: in the same folder as the prodcat.tpl is a tab.tpl and index.php

tab.tpl has this line

<li><a class="homefeatured">{l s='By Category' mod='prodcat'}</a></li>

and index.php has

header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');

header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');

header('Location: ../');
exit;

Comment: it is not an naswer on my questions, please do exactly what I ask you if you need help, there is 2 simple questions. Also, what presta core version you use? it > 1.5.x?

Comment: I did try to clear cache and I am using  1.6.0.14 

I haven't found any file named prodcat.php

Comment: Check please next, into your `themes/your-theme-name/modules/` is there a `prodcat` folder and tpl file(s) prodcat.tpl? If yes, you need to edit this file to change html structure, instead of tpl's from /modules/ folder. (Also in this folder `modules/prodcat/` which `.php` files do you have? I'm just interested)

Comment: I checked into /var/www/html/themes/theme1208/modules
and there's no prodcat folder.

there's no prodcat.tpl file in /var/www/html/themes/theme1208
and /var/www/html/themes/theme1208/modules :(

in modules/prodcat, there's index.php file and a prodcat.php file too afterall :O

Comment: here is the contents of prodcat.php

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6lznTnf5kMdZjdVUDU2UTAtZDQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92403/discussion-between-sergii-p-and-johanna-cristine-dy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

final answer,
when you edit tpl/js/css files, after edit is done, you need to go into backoffice tab 
`Advanced parameters -> Performance` and press `Clear cache` button.

or

if you will have ongoing changes during some time period you can set Samrty cache option in e.g. `Recompile templates if the files have been updated` state.

Answer (score 0):

go to `Advanced parameters -> Performance`
and choose `Force Compilation` under the **Template compilation** dropdown